# trying to get iisnode v0.2.7-x86 / node v0.10.24-x86 working on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, node.js, iisnode

I've spent hours trying to setup iisnode and keep getting stuck at this error when I navigate to any of the sample apps:

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture stdout and stderr output from node.exe. Please check that the identity of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the node.js application is located. Alternatively you can disable logging by setting system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled element of web.config to 'false'.
```

-The iisnode/www folder is readable/writable for iusr and iis_iusrs
-Node.exe is executable by them too

-There is a mapping setup for each of the sample applications in web.config and I can see this in iis as well.

-I've also tried x64 bit versions of iisnode and nodejs without any difference in the error

-application pool is set to enable 32-bit applications

I'm out of ideas as to what to do other than install some previous version.  Anyone run into this problem and find a solution?

edit: etw trace -- http://pastebin.com/heHTpCei

Comment: I know this sounds trivial, but uninstalling/reinstalling iisnode (version 0.2.7) helped things for me. I had to remove iisnode from programs list, then delete the environment variables. I had such a time with this error too but did end up getting it to work. AH! Also: did you run setupexamples.bat from the iisnode folder under an admin command prompt? This *must* be done with certain iisnode versions.